# Prevent hotlinking, no "www"

Tags: .htaccess

I have read many website tutorials about hotlinking protection.
Waste of time.
So I decided to ask here.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

**http://www.domain.com/image.png = Protected**

**http://domain.com/image.png = Unprotected**

Adding

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+.)?domain.com [NC]
```

Actually

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Did not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: I tested by w3schools html. My images is domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/image.png

Comment: How can this be tested by `w3schools.com`? Just test as I wrote above and see what happens.

Comment: Did you test the way I wrote above?

Comment: This have something to be with WordPress. Upload folder is protected with above, but not themes folder.

Comment: I tested from Firefox yes. Still, the same.

Comment: Ok post your complete .htaccess in your question? what is full URL you're trying?